# How to set true the ui/switches in list-view (NativeScript)?

Tags: listview, nativescript, uiswitch

I have a **listview** with a switch component each, and in the footer a button with the function to set true or false all the switches.
The next code is for set the switches to true:

```
var listView1 = view.getViewById(page, "listView");
var label = listView.getViewById('id_check');  
label.checked = true;
```

But I can only set the state of one item, I need to change the state of all items. How to do?

[image]

Thanks

EDITED:

I write the following code but I have an error:

```
for (var i = 0, size = historiqueList.length; i < size ; i++) {
var listView = view.getViewById(page, "listView1");
var label = listView.getItem(i).id_check;
label.checked = true; 
}
```

Error: Cannot set property 'checked'

Answer (score 0):

For your description I think you are referencing all switches with the same id, so when you try to get access to them you only get access to last one referenced. Try to use an array where you can store them all and loop it to change all values when needed.

Comment: If that's the case - that's easier to do in the xml definition for the list-item. Set the checked attribute to true.

Answer (score 0):

You have to intercept the onItemLoading event.

The following is pseudo-code for NS with TS.

```
public onItemLoading(args) {
let item : ListItem = this._listItemArray.getItem( args.itemIndex );

let switch = args.view.getViewById("switch");

switch.enabled = true;  // this could be incorrect
}
```

This is RadListView - but I'm sure ListView is similar.

this._listItemArray is the data-array displayed in the ListView.

Comment: Thanks. I write that: **for (var i = 0, size = historiqueList.length; i < size ; i++) {
var listView = view.getViewById(page, "listView1");
 var label = listView .getItem(i).id_check;
 label.checked = true; 
    }** but I have an error: Cannot set property 'checked'